# Extraer Texto Entre comillas Dobles PHP

Tags: php

Lo que quiero es poder sacar el texto de unas palabras dentro de una frase que están dentro de unas comillas dobles.
**EJEMPLO:** `"prueba1"` y `"prueba2"`
de esa frase quisiera poder sacar en variables independientes el texto `"prueba1"` y en otra variable el texto `"prueba2"`.
había estado checando este código pero no funciona como lo quiero

```
 $texto = 'codigo cualquiera 1
 [begin]
 "derecho" <--- match a este
 123
 hola "justicia" <-- math a este otro
 "AND"
 [end]
 [otro]
 "hola" <--- a este no
 [otro]';

 //Aplicar el regex
 $regex = '/(?:\G(?!\A)|\[begin])[^["]*(?:\[(?!end])[^["]*)*"([^"]*)"/';
 preg_match_all($regex, $texto, $resultado);

 //Imprimir resultados del primer grupo, que es un array dentro de 
 $resultado[1]
 echo join("\n", $resultado[1]);
 ?>
```

Comment: puedes explicar mejor el problema y el resultado que necesitas?

Comment: si bueno es decir si tengo esa frase de prueba: "nombre" y "apellido", lo que quiero es extraer en una variable el texto que esta entre las primeras comillas dobles ("nombre") y en otra variable el texto que esta entre las comillas dobles luego de la letra y ("apellido")

Comment: Puedes acceder mediante `echo "<br />". $resultado[1][0];
echo "<br />". $resultado[1][1];
echo "<br />". $resultado[1][2];` , Yo creo que lo que comentas ya lo tienes, puedes acceder a las tres partes extraídas accediendo dentro del array, o no entiendo que necesitas.

Comment: gracias Eduard Pinuaga me sirve lo que has comentado y siquiera por ejemplo tomar solo el valor que esta fuera de las comillas  "nombre" y "apellido", en este caso la letra y?

Answer (score 0):

```
//En el siguiente String estarán los textos entre comillas dobles.
$string = 'prueba test 1 "hola" prueba test 2 "como estas"';
//En esta variable obtenemos el largo del string en un numero
$len = strlen($string);
//Definimos una variable contable que va incrementando para contar cuantas comillas (") hay en el $string
$contador = 0;
//Definimos una variable array para guardar las posiciones de las comillas
$array = array();
//recorremos el texto por cada uno de sus caracteres según su largo ($len)
for($i = 0; $i < $len;$i++){
  //Esta variable obtiene el carácter que vamos recorriendo del $string
  $val = substr($string, $i, 1);
      //Se valida si el carácter equivale a "
      if($val == '"'){
              //Se adiciona +1 a las comillas encontradas
              $contador++;
              //Guardamos la posición de la comilla en el array
              $array[] = $i+1;
    }
}
//Definimos una variable para recorrer el array
$posicion = 0;
//Mientras el contador de comillas sea mayor a 1 se hace el loop
while($contador > 1){
  //imprime el texto entre las posiciones de las comillas del array con el valor de $posicion
  echo substr($string, $array[$posicion], ($array[$posicion+1]-$array[$posicion]-1));
  //salto de linea
  echo "<br>";
  //restamos 2 al contador para ir condicionando el while
  $contador = $contador -2;
  //adicionamos 2 a la posición para consultas las siguientes 2 comillas
  $posicion = $posicion +2;
}
```

**resultado:**

hola

como estas

Comment: Y si explicas tu código? Para que a toda la comunidad nos quede claro que hiciste, quitaste o agregaste?

Comment: no hay problema, lo editaré agregando los comentarios.
este código puede ser una alternativa a lo solicitado para extraer los textos entre 2 comillas dobles (")

Comment: kevin y en que variable se almacena cada palabra? no veo que tenga una especifica....es decir no veo que tenga una variable para cada palabra...gracias de antemano

Comment: @cgr lo que se puede hacer es crear un array e ir guardándole en esta.

Comment: Aunque no esté mal, se puede mejorar el algoritmo sin tener que usar 2 bucles usando la función explode

Answer (score 0):

Una solución elegante sería usar la función **explode** de php que a partir de un string crea un array según los delimitadores que uses:

```
$cadena = 'hola-qué-tal-';
$array = explode('-', $cadena); //se usa - como delimitador
// $array contiene el array: ["hola", "qué", "tal", ""]
```

De esa manera los elementos del array resultante en posición impar serán las palabras que se encuentran entre comillas, así el código resultante sería:

```
$string = 'prueba test 1 "hola" prueba test 2 "como estas"';
// Se crea el array usando " como delimitador
$array = explode('"', $string);
$palabras = array();

// Se recorre el array para recorrer las palabras entre comillas
//    que son las posiciones impares del array
for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i=$i+2){
    // Este if sirve para no mostrar el último elemento si hay número impar de comillas
    // ejemplo: hola "Ana" qué tal "va" la mañana "hoy
    if($i!=(count($array)-1) || count($array)%2!==0) {
        echo $array[$i] .'<br>';
        $palabras[] = $array[$i];
    }
}
// en la variable $palabras tendrás un array con las palabras entrecomilladas
```